# Help me improve my continuous deployment workflow

Tags: php, workflow, continuous-integration, hudson, selenium-rc

**I've been developing a workflow for practicing a mostly automated [continuous deployment](http://www.startuplessonslearned.com/2009/02/work-in-small-batches.html) cycle for a PHP project.** I'd like some feedback on possible process or technical bottlenecks in this workflow, suggestions for improvement, and ideas for how to better automate and increase the ease-of-use for my team.

---

### **Core components**:

- [`Hudson`](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Home) CI server
- `Git` and [`GitHub`](http://www.github.com)
- [`PHPUnit`](http://www.phpunit.de/) unit tests
- [`Selenium RC`](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)
- [`Sauce OnDemand`](http://saucelabs.com/how-it-works) for automated, cross-browser, cloud testing with `Selenium RC`
- [`Puppet`](http://www.puppetlabs.com/puppet/introduction/) for automating test server deployments
- [`Gerrit`](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) for Git code review
- [`Gerrit Trigger`](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Gerrit+Trigger) for `Hudson`

---

**EDIT**: I've changed the workflow graphic to take ircmaxwell's contributions into account by: removing `PHPUnit`'s extension for `Selenium RC` and running those tests only as part of the QC stage; adding a QC stage; moving UI testing after code review but before merges; moving merges after the QC stage; moving deployment after the merge.

This workflow graphic describes the process. My questions / thoughts / concerns follow.

[image: Continuous Deployment Workflow]

### **My concerns / thoughts / questions**:

- Overall difficulty using this system.
- Time involvement.
- Difficulty employing `Gerrit`.
- Difficulty employing `Puppet`.
- We'll be deploying on `Amazon EC2` instances later. If we're going about setting up `Debian` packages with `Puppet` and deploying to `Linode` slices now, is there a potential for a working deployment on `Linode` to break on `EC2`? Should we instead be doing our builds and deployments on `EC2` from the get-go?
- Another question re: `EC2` and `Puppet`. We're also considering using Scalr as a solution. Would it make as much sense to avoid the overhead of `Puppet` for this alone and invest in Scalr instead? I have a secondary (ha!) concern here about cost; the `Selenium` tests shouldn't be running ***that*** often that `EC2` build instances will be running 24/7, but for something like a five-minute build, paying for an hour of `EC2` usage seems a bit much.
- Possible process bottlenecks on merges.
- Could "A" be moved?

**Credits**: Portions of this workflow are [inspired by Digg's awesome post on continuous deployment](http://about.digg.com/blog/continuous-deployment-code-review-and-pre-tested-commits-digg4). The workflow graphic above is [inspired by the Android OS Project](http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html).

Comment: so - do you think this kind of a process is worth it? Seems to me there is not too much time left for actual development.

Comment: @Andre No, it's not worth it for the amount of effort I, on my own, would have to put into this system, as described. That said, PHP Fog has a decent solution for this which is worth watching.

Comment: which tool did you use to create this workflow diagram?

Comment: @Jason http://www.omnigroup.com/products/OmniGraffle/

Comment: Too real and interesting of a question. Why hasn't it been closed? Or has it? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How many people are working on it?  If you only have maybe 10 or 20 developers, I'm not sure it will make sense to put such an elaborate workflow into place.  If you're managing 500, sure...

My personal feeling is KISS.  Keep It Simple, Stupid... You want a process that's both efficient, and more important: simple.  If it's complicated, either nobody is going to do it right, or after time parts will slip.  If you make it simple, it will become second nature and after a few weeks nobody would question the process (Well, the semantics of it anyway)...

And the other personal feeling is always run all of your UNIT tests.  That way, you can skip a whole decision tree in your flow chart.  After all, what's more expensive, a few minutes of CPU time, or the brain cycles to understand the difference between the partial test passing and the massive test failing.  Remember, a fail is a fail, and there's no practical reason that code should ever be shown to a reviewer that has the potential to fail the build.

Now, Selenium tests are typically quite expensive, so I might agree to push those off until after the reviewer approves.  But you'll need to think about that one...

Oh, and if I was implementing this, I would put a formal QC stage in there.  I want human testers to look at any changes that are being made.  Yes, Selenium can verify the things you know about, but only a human can find things you didn't think of.  Feed back their findings into new Selenium and Integration tests to prevent regressions...

Comment: We're a very small team at the moment, so I certainly agree that KISS is the way to go. That said, I'd like a process that scales, though that doesn't necessarily mean one that's complex. At the moment our process is continuous integration only and it has become basically second nature. Write and run tests on local; commit to master when ready; Hudson builds and runs tests on the server and reports back. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: As for the unit tests, also agree wholeheartedly. It's Selenium that'll be the slowest. So when I wrote in the workflow that it's a portion of unit tests, I really meant ALL the PHPUnit tests and none of the Selenium tests.

Comment: Well, remember that if you create your process right from the begining, you can scale it up in sections.  So basically you'd have a series of stages (test, verify, qc and deploy, for example).  Then, when you need to add process, you add it where it needs it.  If you notice the verification stage is taking too much time, or isn't working right, you adjust that then.  You don't need to have an elaborate system for it to scale.  You just need an intelligently designed simple system that people believe in.  If others aren't committed, it won't happen, no matter how good the workflow...

Comment: +1 for the edit re: QC. Though what I'm thinking is that in an alpha stage of the product, we can pushing code to production and getting feedback from testers, which can then be written into the new Selenium tests. Your thoughts on where/how to do it?

Comment: Well, IMHO you want a QC from pre-alpha all the way through.  Otherwise you may miss an architectural bug, and it's far more expensive to fix later. Have your QC team write and maintain the Selenium tests. That way, it's in their interest to write them (since it makes their lives easier), and it's their problem to verify if one fails (that it wasn't a false positive).  I'm a fan of "escalation". Where you have Dev->Review->QC->Production.  One level can push to the next, but no further. So that way once it's out of one hand, they don't need to worry unless they hear back (and can continue on).

Comment: Gotcha re: QC and agreed. As per your overall sense that this is overly complex, I'm just wondering what steps you'd omit or simplify. Since Gerrit's all automated and all about code review, I'm not sure those aspects are really all that complex. My thought is that maybe I should eliminate using `PHPUnit`'s Selenium RC extension and instead write those tests for the `Sauce OnDemand` portion. Then after code review, Gerrit performs a merge rather than a build. That eliminates basically the "6th" and "7th" grid rows from the workflow.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking at it, I can't really see much to get rid of.  Perhaps run the Sauce tests before the merge as well (since that's testing the code), and also run all unit tests when you are currently running the Sauce tests (since you're testing the merge, rather than just the local copy).  I guess I'm just hesitant at any significant level of complexity (even automated) since it's going to be tougher to maintain or modify the automation later...  Use automation to simply, but don't make it complex since then you're tied to the complexity (and when something breaks, have fun)...

Comment: I think what's nice about the automation is that `Hudson` and `Puppet` only play minor roles in the automation process. We don't have to change our build much to continue using `Hudson`. And `Gerrit` makes up the rest of the automation and is part-and-parcel with our code review.

Comment: Edited workflow graphic thanks to your contributions. Let me know what you think.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I would do (the focus on "stages", the dedicated QC steps, etc)...  Looks good to me...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Really very deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Importent to make your [tests extremely fast](http://www.slideshare.net/pascallouis/extreme-testing-at-kaching), i.e. no IO and ability to run [parallel](http://eng.kaching.com/2010/02/parallelizing-junit-test-runs.html) and distributed tests. Don't know how applicable it is with php, but if you can test units of code with in memory db and mock the environment you'll be better off.

If you have a QA/QC or any human in the way between the commit and production you would have a problem getting to a [full continuous deployment](http://eng.kaching.com/2010/09/devops-cafe-on-continuous-deployment.html). The key is your trust your testing, monitoring and auto response (immune system) enough to eliminate error prone process evolving humans from your system.

Answer (score 2):

All handovers between functions have the effect of slowing things down, and with that, an increase of the amount of change (and hence risk) that goes in to a deployment.

Manual quality gates are by definition an acceptance that quality has not been built in from the start. The only reason code needs to be reviewed later is because there is some belief that the quality is not good enough already.

I'm currently trying to remove formal code review from our pipelines for exactly this reason. It causes feedback delays, and quoting Martin Fowler:

"The whole point of Continuous Integration is to provide rapid feedback. Nothing sucks the blood of a CI activity more than a build that takes a long time. "

Instead I'd like to make code review something that submitters request if required, or otherwise is done at the time of coding by team members, perhaps a la XP pair programming.

I think it should be your goal that once the code is merged to source control, that there is absolutely *no* more manual intervention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is relevant to PHP, but you can replace at least at least some of the code review stage with static analysis.

The quality of code reviews is relying on the quality of the reviewers, while static analysis relies on best practices and patterns, and is fully automatic. I'm not saying that code reviews should be abandoned, I simply think it can be done off-line.

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Comment: Would you mind expanding upon this some? I'm honestly quite new to all of this (been developing for just under four months now) so I'd appreciate some further explication.