# how was this diagram created?

Tags: flow-diagram

[Help me improve my continuous deployment workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703373/help-me-improve-my-continuous-deployment-workflow)

how was this diagram created?
any free / open source tool i can use to create this very same diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.drawanywhere.com/videotour.aspx